# MongoClient Not working for PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, client, driver, laravel-5

I have tried hell lot of solutions but nothing has worked yet,
I have installed mongodb driver and it does come up in phpinfo() page I have tried to use it in cli mode it works fine (I am using laravel so I can migrate to mongodb without no problems), I have added extension=mongo.so in both cli folder and apache2 folder still MongoClient class is not being loaded, really have no clue why? please help.

here is my php -ri mongo details.

```
mongo

MongoDB Support => enabled
Version => 1.6.2
Streams Support => enabled
SSL Support => enabled
                   Supported Authentication Mechanisms                   
MONGODB-CR => enabled
SCRAM-SHA-1 => enabled
MONGODB-X509 => enabled
GSSAPI (Kerberos) => disabled
PLAIN => disabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mongo.default_host => localhost => localhost
mongo.default_port => 27017 => 27017
mongo.chunk_size => 261120 => 261120
mongo.cmd => $ => $
mongo.native_long => 1 => 1
mongo.long_as_object => 0 => 0
mongo.allow_empty_keys => 0 => 0
mongo.ping_interval => 5 => 5
mongo.is_master_interval => 15 => 15
```

BTW using laravel 5, if this has to do with anything.

thank you

Comment: Which OS are you using? Linux or Mac?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 14.04, to be exact

Answer (score 2):

May be you are installed `php5-mongo` ubuntu package, instead install the mongo extension via pecl.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev make php-pear
sudo pecl install mongo
sudo echo "extension=mongo.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini
```

Comment: I followed the same installation steps to install mongodb extension, no worries I fixed it.